# Changing Android ListView selected row properties outside listeners

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an Android ListView in which I want to change some selected row properties like background color, Image view etc.

I know how to change in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` by getting the view object.

But now the problem is that I want to modify this row properties outside the listeners. I have searched a lot but not able to found solution for this.

I have read the documentation of ListView and BaseAdapter also here:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: outside the listeners? means not on item click?

Comment: @Naser  Yes .......... How to get the views object for differnet rows.

Comment: you want to change background color and imageView of multiple list items without clicking on listview?

Comment: @Naser  yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using custom adapter, if so, then follow next steps.

set background (or whatever changes you want) in getView() method if that current view satisfies your condition. Otherwise reset background to default. For example I want to show alternate rows in different color, then I will do like follows

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    } else {}

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
    }
    return view;
}
```